Find an offending line in a robust pattern
Some context
I am working with (La)TeX. It has few types of if-conditionals. They typically look like \if, \ifx, \ifnum etc. All of these are closed using \fi with an optional \else in between. If an \if-type statement is not closed with \fi, it generates a warning (sadly, not an error). I have one such warning. I have checked my code thoroughly and I am 100% sure that the offending if-statement is not mine. So it has to be from a file I depend on and there are many such files. There is a built in mechanism for tracing the ifs, but it is... well, sadist! It combines ALL the types of if-s from ALL the files and creates a huge log which is absolutely not intuitive. The log with which I am working right now is around 85000 lines long!! It looks like this:
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\ifx: (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\else: \ifx (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\ifx: (level 4) entered on line 50}
{\else: \ifx (level 4) entered on line 50}
{\fi: \ifx (level 4) entered on line 50}
{\fi: \ifx (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\ifx: (level 3) entered on line 50}
{\else: \ifx (level 3) entered on line 50}

The warning message I get says:
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)

What I have tried so far
I simply picked up the common points from the warning message as well as the messages seen in the log. There are two regex lines which helped me to simplify the problem. Since the warning specifically mentioned line 21, I made use of it and it also mentioned \ifx, so I ignored all the other types of if. First I regex-searched for:
\\ifx\: \((.*?)\) entered on line 21\}

This has 480 matches.
\\fi: \\ifx \((.*?)\) entered on line 21\}

This has 479 matches.
What do I want?
I want something that will report the number of the offending line. Basically there will be some match from the search \\ifx\: \((.*?)\) entered on line 21\} which doesn't have a partnering \\fi: \\ifx \((.*?)\) entered on line 21\}. That's it. A minimal code to work with:
{\ifx: (level 1) entered on line 21}
{\ifx: (level 2) entered on line 21}
{\ifx: (level 3) entered on line 21}
{\ifx: (level 4) entered on line 21}
{\fi: \ifx (level 3) entered on line 21}
{\fi: \ifx (level 2) entered on line 21}
{\fi: \ifx (level 1) entered on line 21}

Whatever we use to achieve this, should just tell me "The offending \ifx is on line number 4".
I am on a GNU Linux machine. The prospective solutions can be in GNU Bash, GNU Emacs, (La)TeX or anything that may work with these.
